# My main goal is to monitor Tomcat directory, if any user modify files in tomcat directory; print that user name in the log;

Tags: linux, shell-script, linux-kernel, tomcat, inotify

```
#!/bin/bash

watchDir="$1"
watchDir2="$2"
date1=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
inotifywait -m -r --exclude \.log "$watchDir" "$watchDir2" -e attrib,delete,delete_self,close,close_write,close_nowrite,create,open,modify,move,moved_to,moved_from |
    while read -r file; do
        name=$(stat -c '%U' $file 2>/dev/null)
            date=$(stat -c %Y $file 2>/dev/null | awk '{print strftime("%d-%m-%Y %T", $1,$2)}')
        fileName=${file/* CREATE /}
        echo "[${date%.*}]" "File: '$fileName'  User: '$name'" >>  /var/log/inotify/inotify-$date1.log
    done
```

Comment: i recommend to keep file names clean and handle nul separated. therefore always quote variables

Comment: @alecxs My main goal is to monitor Tomcat directory, if any user modify, copy or delete any file in tomcat directory; i have to print that user name in the log; 
I didn't get your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of study i found the limitations useful;
finding user who changed a file wont work with inotify.

Please read Limitations http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/inotify.7.html

Limitations and caveats

The inotify API provides no information about the user or process that triggered the inotify event. In particular, there is no easy way for a process that is monitoring events via inotify to distinguish events that it triggers itself from those that are triggered by other processes.

---

---